# Subprocess Popen with stdin and stdout --- always hangs up

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need to communicate with a flash process started with a command line.
Unfortunately in case of an error the flasher program expects a "Enter" Key.

I have installed python 3.7.2 and use `subprocess` with PyCharm. I'm able to start the process with `popen`, but the `stdout` seems to be empty even with `bufsize = 0` or `1` and even with a flush command: `p.stdout.flush():` here is the code:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(stringCall, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True)

time.sleep(2)
proc.stdout.flush()
```

......with this one the program hangs for ever:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line)
```

I found a lot of examples for that problem, but none work for me. Perhaps it is for Python 2.x while I'm using 3.7.2...
I expected some reaction in the `proc.stdout` container as it becomes filled, or that the example code is able to run.

Comment: Hi, it's me again, Matze: a totally different approach would be with win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")... I have some lines of code for that  and it is working with some input (great), but I was not able to get the output (only SendKeys Method found yet !!!!)